# Mui Autocomplete with inputLabelProps shrink true in custom theme

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete

When using TextField we can add a custom theme to make the label shrink by default

```js
 MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: { InputLabelProps: { shrink: true } },
 },
```

When using it with [Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) component.

```js
 <Autocomplete
   fullWidth
   options={options}
   clearOnBlur
   disablePortal
   popupIcon={false}
   id="combo-box-demo"
   renderInput={params => {
      return (
       <TextField {...params} label="Movie" variant="standard" />
      );
   }}
  />
```

[image: Autocomplete doesn't shrink]

What I have tried is that we can add it in autocomplete `renderInput` props

```js
renderInput={({ InputLabelProps, params })=> {
 return (
   <TextField {...params}
     label="Movie" variant="standard" 
     InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
      ...InputLabelProps,
     }}
   />

 );
}}
```

but the problem is we need to pass it everytime we want to render the autocomplete and it could be easily forgotten.

It would be convenient if we can also make it default in custom theme.

```js
 MuiAutoComplete: {
      defaultProps: { InputLabelProps: { shrink: true } },
 },
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass `shrink: true` in the default props to **InputLabel** itself like that

```
MuiInputLabel: {
   defaultProps: { shrink: true },
},
```